# Mongoose: How to return array of Object _ids within aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I can format my response into this, an array of objects of _ids:

```
[ { "_id": "5d703c09af11414e538fe95b" }, { "_id": "5d704b9b1ba3f75232d778d4" }, { "_id": "5d704bbe1ba3f75232d779de" } ]
```

However is it possible, within the aggregation pipeline, to transform it into just an array of the Object ids:

```
["5d703c09af11414e538fe95b", "5d704b9b1ba3f75232d778d4", "5d704bbe1ba3f75232d779de"]
```

I am aware that I could simply take the original response and map over it but I am unsure if we could do this directly within mongooose.

Answer (score 0):

use $group operator as

```
 {$group:{_id:null,ids:{$push:"$_id"}}}
```

this will return an array of ids